# List all users and last time they read mail, pipeing to multiple output

Tags: debian, text-processing, command-line

I have one system that I would like to do a little clean up, so I would like to get all user accounts and last date they accessed they mail. It is a Debian system.

So far I got to this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 finger | grep "Mail last read"
```

But I don't know how to write that username in front of

> Mail last read Sun Aug 12 03:06 2012 (CEST)

Comment: also asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12006714/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
for USER in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do MAILINFO=$(finger $USER | grep "Mail last read"); echo "$USER - $MAILINFO"; done
```

I think you should get the gist ... you need to manipulate the return from the grep "Mail last read" a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd |
xargs finger |
awk  '/^Login:/ { user = $2 }
      /^Mail last read/ {print user, $0}'
```

Or alternatively

```
ls -ltu /var/spool/mail
```

(or `/var/mail` or wherever the mail is located on your system).

Comment: `ls -ltu /var/spool/mail` will show the last time they *received* mail, not the last time it was *read*.

Comment: @bahamat `-u` shows the atime. That's what `finger` looks at anyway.